# How to bind the list which is present in the ViewModel to the input field like Radio Button

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public class AssessmentResponseViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AssessmentType { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public string TakenBy { get; set; }
        public List<AssessmentQuestionViewModel> AllQuestions { get; set; }
    }

public class AssessmentQuestionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int Response { get; set; }

}
```

In the Post method of Assessment, I want All responses.

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Assessment()
        {
            AssessmentResponseViewModel assessmentResponse = new AssessmentResponseViewModel();
            assessmentResponse.AssessmentType = 4;
            assessmentResponse.AllQuestions = _assessmentService.GetAssessmentQuestionsByType(4);
            return View(assessmentResponse);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Assessment(AssessmentResponseViewModel Response)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Actually, this application is just like an assessment where different questions are present.

Here is the Code that how I'm currently binding

```
@model LectureSoft.ViewModel.AssessmentResponseViewModel
<div class="container-fluid mt-1">

    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body" style="color: black;">
                <p class=" mt-2">Please Answer these questions based on your usual practice.</p>
                <p class=" font-weight-bold">Estimate how often in your teaching and couses(s) that you do the following.</p>
                <p class="font-weight-bold mt-2">GUIDE: Never-0%, Rarely-25%, Sometimes-50%, Often-75%, Always-100% of the time</p>
                <hr>
                <div class="mclass" style="background-color: white;">
                    <form asp-action="Assessment" asp-controller="Home" method="post" id="QuestionsForm">

                        @if (Model.AllQuestions != null)
                        {
                            int i = 1;
                            @foreach (var item in Model.AllQuestions)
                            {

                                <div class="row rclass">
                                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 qclass">
                                        <h4 style="color: #08c7bf;">Question @i</h4>
                                        <label class="text1">@item.Question</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 oclass justify-content-center align-self-center">
                                        <div class="row nclass">
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                                                <h7>Never</h7><br>                                               
                                                <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="1" class="margin-top" name="@item.Id">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                                                <h7>Rarely</h7><br>
                                                <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" checked value="2" class="margin-top" name="@item.Id">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
                                                <h7>Sometime</h7><br>
                                                <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="3" class="margin-top" name="@item.Id">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                                                <h7>Often</h7><br>
                                                <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="4" class="margin-top" name="@item.Id">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
                                                <h7>Always</h7><br>
                                                <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="5" class="margin-top" name="@item.Id">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                i++;
                            }
                        }



                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn mb-1 btn-primary px-5" style="background-color: #08c7bf !important;
                                        border-color: #08c7bf !important;">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But I'm getting Null in the List of "AllQuestions". Please let me know how I can bind all question with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the value and property you want to bind to the `AllQuestions`.

1. From you razor view,  `Question` in `AllQuestions` cannot be bind to the backend because it is a label. If you want to bind it, you need set a hidden input element for it.
2. Then I see you use `Id` and `Response` as `id` and `name` attribute in radio button. You need to know the backend code **receives value by getting value attribute** in radio button, the value in your code is hard coded(`value="1",value="2",value="3"...`). And the model binding system in asp..net core **binds the property by name attribute**.

For example, your code use `name="@item.Id"` and `value="1"` in radio button, in this scenario you will get a model with a nested model named `Item` and in `Item` model contains `Id` property and the `Id` value is `1`.

3. Actually `asp-for` in your code is useless. Because default `asp-for` will generate the `id` and `name`, but you specify the `id` and `name`, they will override the `asp-for` generated html.

Assume that you pass the hard coded value to backend and bind it to `Response`. Here is a working demo:

Change the name attribute(`name="AllQuestions[@i-1].Response"`) in each radio button and add hidden input for `Question`:

```
@if (Model.AllQuestions != null)
{
    int i = 1;
    @foreach (var item in Model.AllQuestions)
    {

        <div class="row rclass">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 qclass">
                <h4 style="color: #08c7bf;">Question @i</h4>
                <label class="text1">@item.Question</label>
                <input asp-for="@item.Question" name="AllQuestions[@(i-1)].Question" hidden/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 oclass justify-content-center align-self-center">
                <div class="row nclass">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                        <h7>Never</h7><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="1" class="margin-top" 
                               name="AllQuestions[@(i-1)].Response">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                        <h7>Rarely</h7><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" checked value="2" class="margin-top" 
                               name="AllQuestions[@(i-1)].Response">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
                        <h7>Sometime</h7><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="3" class="margin-top" 
                               name="AllQuestions[@(i-1)].Response">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4">
                        <h7>Often</h7><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="4" class="margin-top" 
                               name="AllQuestions[@(i-1)].Response">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
                        <h7>Always</h7><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="@item.Id" asp-for="@item.Response" value="5" class="margin-top" 
                               name="AllQuestions[@(i-1)].Response">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        i++;
    }
}
```

The result(I choose 1,2,3,4 in frontend):

[image]

**Any way, you need remember one thing: The model binding bind the property by `name` in html and bind the value by `value` in html.**

Comment: Yes, this is what that I exactly need :) Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks Again.